# Avoid catastrophic backtracking for my current requirement

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have to match certain certain criteria in a phrase, (group of words)(anything in between)(group of words) for example:

```
(mirror|reflect|serve|adapt)(\s*\w+\s*\W*\s*)*?(population|client|customer|stakeholder|market|society|culture|consumer|end-user)
```

So anytime in a phrase I have "mirror bananas banannas population" I want to match it. Is this the best solution ? Is it prone to catastrophic backtracking ?

Comment: Just replace `(\s*\w+\s*\W*\s*)*?` with `.*` and you're set. Job done.

Comment: Or replace `(\s*\w+\s*\W*\s*)` with `.` to keep it non greedy. If you are not referring to the capturing groups in your code or tool, you might make them non capturing `(?:` if that is supported.

Comment: Questions: does "anything in between" include nothing or must there be at least one non-space character? What would you expect to match in the string "mirror bananas population bananas customer"?

Comment: Pardon, anything in between means there can also be nothing, so that w+ is actually a w*.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Won't this risk catastrophic backtracking with long phrases ? Also, can I make it stop at the first occurrence ?

Comment: Yes, `(\s*\w+\s*\W*\s*)*?` makes it prone to catastrophic backtracking. Try against [`mirror banana banannas populatio`](https://regex101.com/r/HHDO2p/1). Why not use `(mirror|reflect|serve|adapt)(.*?)(population|client|customer|stakeholder|market|society|culture|consumer|end-user)`?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for your example. I'm using .* now, and indeed your answer makes it stop at the first match, however on the same website you send me it shows that using (.*?) increases the steps ? Will that increase CB chances? In the end my phrases are not that big, but I cannot estimate for all of them because I have a large dataset, I just want to have the solution that is less prone to CB.

Comment: What is the regex engine you are using? What is the size of texts you want to pass to the regex? BTW, are the groups built dynamically in code or do you create the groups manually?

Comment: I am using re in python. I am parsing data from hundreds of PDF files and each file I extract paragraphs, for every paragraph I extract phrases, and on the phrases I run my regexes, so the size is variable, but as far as text is involved, it should be medium-small. The groups are build manually, I load them from a JSON file.

Comment: I would say your only way with regex is what I showed. Compile with `re.S` to enable `.` to match newlines, too. Or, parse the strings with string methods.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your message, I have although eliminated newlines while parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(\s*\w+\s*\W*\s*)*?` part may lead to catastrophic backtracking since the only obligatory pattern inside the `*?`-quantified group is `\w+` and it is enclosed with other optional patterns (`\s*` and `\W*` may match empty strings and note that adjoining `*`-quantified patterns like `\s*\W*\s*` match match the same chars, which is bad practice leading to catastrophic backtracking).

If you [test your regex against `mirror banana banannas populatio`](https://regex101.com/r/HHDO2p/1) you will get the catastrophic backtracking error.

The best regex way in your case, that is, when you read the leading/trailing word lists from a JSON file, is with a regex like

```
(?:leading_word1|leading_word2|...|leading_wordN)(.*?)(?:trailing_word1|trailing_word2|...|trailing_wordN)
```

The value you need will be in Group 1, or all values in a list if you use `re.findall` (you say you are using Python).